# Integrate several group by queries (joining one table with a variety of others and counting the matches)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, group-by

In an application, I need to display the number *(count)* of customers, products, {insert other entities here} (from `db.Custmers`, `db.Products`, etc.) per status (from `db.Geodata`).

A result might look like

> ```
> Customers: { Status = "OK", Count = 59 }
>            { Status = "INVALID", Count = 14 }
>            { Status = "NO_RESULT", Count = 29 }
>
> Products:  { Status = "OK", Count = 541 }
>            { Status = "INVALID", Count = 33 }
>            { Status = "NO_RESULT", Count = 42 }
> ```

So I wrote a query....

```
from customer in db.Kunden
join pin in db.Geodata
    on customer.AdressNr equals pin.AdressNr
group customer by pin.Status
into groups
select new {Status = groups.Key, Count = groups.Count()};
```

and another one....

```
from product in db.Products
join pin in db.Geodata
    on product.AdressNr equals pin.AdressNr
group product by pin.Status
into groups
select new {Status = groups.Key, Count = groups.Count()};
```

and few more. They work just fine. But I'm struggling to integrate them all together into one query (and thereby consolidating the duplicated parts, i.e. the last two lines).

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT: can anyone help me improve this question? Is any critical information missing? Is this too localized, or too broad?**

Answer (score 0):

*Even if it may be too late by now it may help you.*

LINQ has not been designed to build its statements like in SQL, where you probably would have used `StringBuilder` or something like that.

The advantage of LINQ over SQL is to have compile-time checking while you are coding. In SQL you have to run your code and do trial & error.

However, I found a similar question which has been asked/answered 5 months after your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797168.

Adopting this method you could have something like the following:

```
public object[] GetCustomers()
{
    return GetEntityCount("Customers");
}

private object[] GetEntityCount(string entityName)
{
    return (from obj in GetSpecificEntity(entityName) join pin ...).ToArray();
}

private IEnumerable GetSpecificEntity(string entityName)
{
    switch (entityName)
    {
        case "Customers": return db.Customers;
    }
}
```