# LINQ dynamic from clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I use dynamic LINQ for creating queries in runtime. Here is an example:

```
var result = dbContext.Table1
.Where(x => x.Field1 == "SomeValue")
.Select(x => new { x.Field1, x.Field2 });
```

Here I can dynamically change where clause and select clause, but is there any way for dynamic from clause?

If I want to change dbContext.Table1 with some other table in runtime? Or I must use SQL for that?

EDIT: About duplicate question suggestion: It is the same question, but there isn't right answer in that question. The answer provided there is not generic enough, I would have to put a case statement for each new table...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a dynamic FROM clause for a LINQ query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796941/how-to-build-a-dynamic-from-clause-for-a-linq-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flowing code to get table value from table name. Hope it helps.

```
var table = (ITable)dbContext.GetType()
                       .GetProperty(tableName)
                       .GetValue(dbContext, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of the entity you need to retrieve, you can use the `Set<>` method of your db context instead of the `Table1` property. For example:

```
var data = dbContext.Set<EntityType>();
```